# Python requests returns 403 even with headers

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get content of website but my requests return me an 403 ERROR.

After searching, I found Network>Headers section to add headers before GET request and tried these headers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = "https://clutch.co/us/agencies/digital-marketing"
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"} 
### Also tried "Referer" , "sec-ch-ua-platform" and "Origin" headers but nothing changed.
html = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS)
print("RESULT:",html)
```

But result didn't change.

Comment: CloudFlare appears to be detecting that you're a bot. They could have some kind of advanced heuristic detection that goes beyond the headers.

Comment: You're being challenged as a bot. You might want to try something like selenium instead which can execute JS.

Comment: I found `cloudscraper` library for these stutations. It can be use instead of google cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to load the page from the Google cache instead directly:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://clutch.co/us/agencies/digital-marketing"
cache_URL = "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:"


def get_data(link):
    hdr = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    }
    req = requests.get(cache_URL + link, headers=hdr)
    content = req.text
    return content


soup = BeautifulSoup(get_data(url), 'html.parser')
for h3 in soup.select('h3.company_info'):
    print(h3.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
WebFX
Ignite Visibility
SmartSites
Thrive Internet Marketing Agency
Lilo Social
NEWMEDIA.COM
Funnel Boost Media
Direct Online Marketing
SeedX Inc.
Impactable

...
```